# How to include the x-implements flag in internal Openapi YAML models only?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using use the x-implements flag for my openapi schema as follows:

```
paths:
  /pets:
    get:
      summary: List all pets
      operationId: listPets
      tags:
        - pets
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of pets.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'

components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      x-implements: ['com.petstore.PetInterface']
      type: object
      required:
        - name
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        tag:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Tag'
```

I have defined the `com.petstore.PetInterface` in my code. I am generating the code with the maven-openapi-generator and this all works fine for my internal usage. However, I am going to deliver the openapi file to the customer and they don't have this interface. How to deal with this? I was thinking about the following solutions:

1. delete the x-implements flag (manually) before delivering the file to the customer
2. create an internal and external schema, but I guess this results in a lot of code duplications

Are there any better solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was thinking about the following solutions:
>
> 1. delete the x-implements flag (manually) before delivering the file to the customer

This sounds fine and seems to be a common use case, given that tools like [`openapi-filter`](https://github.com/Mermade/openapi-filter) and [`openapi-format`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-format#openapi-filter-options) exist.

In your case, you can automate the deletion of the `x-implements` key by using [`yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/). The example below is for `yq` v4; the `-i` flag updates the input file in-place:

```
# Bash
yq -i 'del(.components.schemas.*["x-implements"])' openapi.yaml

# Windows CMD
yq -i "del(.components.schemas.*[\"x-implements\"])" openapi.yaml
```